# What's a good translation for "Watch Me Research"?

Tags: translation, word-usage

I have a blog called Watch Me Research, where I publish my research on interesting things, and I've been translating my posts to German, publishing them under a subdomain. I'm still learning German (I have for the last five years), and I can't for the life of me come up with a good translation of the blog's name.

I guess, to generalize the question, can you say "watch me *verb*" in the same way as in English?  Is "schau mir forschen" a good translation?

Comment: interesting, could i know the site url?

Comment: Would you mind sharing a few of your attempts? It would probably be helpful to understand, what your "target" is.

Comment: "Schau mir forschen" is terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sieh mich forschen – short, grammatically correct version, but a little poetic.

Comment: Why do you consider this poetic?

Comment: I cannot imagine someone using this phrase in everyday language.

Answer (score 1):

Now the question is what `research` should mean. In English it roughly means something like `gathering information`. When translating to German there is a difference. A journalist does research for an article and a scientist is doing scientific research on a special subject and so on...

For these two cases I suggest these translations:

The journalist: `Sieh' mir beim recherchieren/nachforschen zu`

The scientist: `Sieh' mir beim forschen zu`

EDIT: But neither of these would sound really good as names for a blog, especially not to native germans.

EDIT 2: After some thinking i came up with "Lass uns forschen!" ("Lets research") as a Blog title. Of course that changes the meaning completely but surves the purpose well in my opinion.

Comment: What about `Lass uns forschen!` (`Let's research!`)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Schau mir zu, wie ich forsche` , literally, `Watch me as I research`?

Comment: you need to use the verb `forschen`, not the noun `Forschung`: `wie ich forsche`

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of leaving information out in the title, why not just name it Schau Mal! Or the like?

Comment: I understand. It is indeed a trade-off between style and being specific.